# Работа с процессами в Java

Tags: java, linux, многопоточность

Во всех `UNIX`-системах есть системный вызов дочернего процесса (`fork`). Это означает, что создаетелям любого языка программирование (так кажется мне на первый взгляд) не состяавляет труда сделать библиотечную функцию для работы с этим системным вызовом. Например, в python есть `os.fork()`, которым многие активно пользуются.

Почему в `Java` уделается огромное значение многопоточности (`Thread'ы`) в виде книг, форумов и прочего, но в то же время нет какого-то продвинутого и простого механизма для работы с процессами (`fork'ами`) ?

Comment: java код выполняется не в среде ОС, а в среде виртуальной java-машины и ему доступны те возможности, которые заложены в эту машину. по хорошему не доступна ни одна функция ОС напрямую - все эмулируется. А почему машина сделана так, а не по другому, спросите у Джеймса Гослинга

Comment: Да потому, что на момент выхода самой первой версии Java `fork` уже считался древним ресурсоёмким и неудобным способом обеспечения параллельности, а потоки его выгодной заменой.

Answer (score 0):

Если обратиться к истории - то сначала в JVM были "green threads", которые позволяли планировать потоки независимо от ОС. Это был первый плюс потоков (если не говорить об остальных плюсах зеленых тредов). Потом от них по большей части отказались (за исключением некоторых специфических jvm) - но тем не менее. 
Как второй плюс - переключение между потоками и совместная работа с данными значительно легче при работе с потоками, нежели с разными процессами - так как native потоки изначально работают с общей памятью, их быстрее создавать. 
Ну а если говорить про требования JMM - то там вообще очень много требований, которые, как мне представляется, значительно труднее сделать при реализации на процессах.